# Laravel change migration order

Tags: laravel-5, migration

Is there a way how I can change the migrations order without remaking them all? Because now I have a problem with my foreign keys -_- (working with laravel)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

1. [Roll back all the migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#rolling-back-migrations) (or start with a fresh database);
2. Change the dates that form the first part of the migration filenames so they're in the order you want (eg. for `2014_06_24_134109_update_database.php`, the date & time is 2014-06-24, 13:41:09);
3. Run the migrations again.

With respect to your comment about foreign keys... I'm not sure that the problem is with Laravel. More likely, it's just MySQL.

I avoid foreign keys because once you get a moderately complicated set of relations, you start to run into problems with database consistency like you're seeing - it's hard for the server to figure out what order to create the tables & relationships in, and it starts to cause difficulties with things like dump files (for backups).

Comment: You can split the migration for each table into two migration files, one for the table creation and the other for the table relationships and keep all the update migrations date after all the create ones. that way no issues when rolling back and re-migrating.

Comment: Wouldn't it be quite the perfect solution for laravel to run the foreign key definitions after all the creating is done?

Comment: That might work well for Laravel, but the issue I've seen around foreign key definitions is with tools like `mysqldump` - if you have a bunch of tables with relationships between them, `mysqldump` often writes them out in an order that cannot be successfully re-imported (eg. table A depends on table B and table B depends on table A). Perhaps things have changed in recent years, so YMMV.

Comment: What is the side effect when you change the dates on migrations and  push to production server which has the database with data

Comment: @edgarmlowe That's a good question... I don't know. I suspect that will result in data loss - I wouldn't do it.

Comment: Avoiding foreign keys will cause you more problems than having them. It will warn you about inconsistencies and prevent you (or any other dev who's working in the same project) from messing up eventually when working further into the project. Also, poor the guy who potentially has to pick it up from where you left if you leave the project. I don't downvote the answer because the foreign advice is a side note

Comment: I was under the impression I could just name the migration files with an index number at the front. Turns out, that's wrong. Whatever numbers you use, they must resolve to an actual date/time format!

Comment: @JessycaFrederick Actually you can use any naming scheme you want. The alphabetical  filename order determines the order in which the migration is excuted.

Answer (score 11):

You have to create a custom command that executes 
`php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/name_migration.php` repeately with the migrations's name in the order you want.

Like this:

1. Create Command class with:  `php artisan make:command NameClass`
2. Go to `app/Console/Commands/` and find the class file `NameClass.php`
3. In the NameClass.php you have two attributes `$signature` (the name of the command) and `$description` (Information about what your command does).
4. Set the name and the description of your command.`Ex: protected $signature='namecommand'; protected $descripton = 'This method migrate tables in order'`
5. Inside the NameClass.php you have a method called `handle()`, here you have to declare the code you want to be executed when you write the command.
6. Register your command. Go to `app/Console/Kernel.php and` add your class to the list of Command Classes.
   `protected $commands = [
   Commands\NameClass::class,
   ];`
7. Write the command in the terminal. `php artisan namecommand`

Example:

1. `php artisan make:command MigrateInOrder`
2. app/Console/Commands/MigrateInOrder.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class MigrateInOrder extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'migrate_in_order';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Execute the migrations in the order specified in the file app/Console/Comands/MigrateInOrder.php \n Drop all the table in db before execute the command.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
       /** Specify the names of the migrations files in the order you want to 
        * loaded
        * $migrations =[ 
        *               'xxxx_xx_xx_000000_create_nameTable_table.php',
        *    ];
        */
        $migrations = [ 
                        '2020_04_18_005024_create_users_types.php',
                        '2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php',
                        '2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php',
                        '2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table.php'
        ];

        foreach($migrations as $migration)
        {
           $basePath = 'database/migrations/';          
           $migrationName = trim($migration);
           $path = $basePath.$migrationName;
           $this->call('migrate:refresh', [
            '--path' => $path ,            
           ]);
        }
    }
}
```

4. Go to app/Console/Kernel.php and register your command

```
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\MigrateInOrder::class,
    ];
```

5. Excute the command

```
   php artisan migrate_in_order
```

Answer (score 5):

Taking inspiration from PhpMyAdmin, I put all foreign keys definitions in a specific far future file, eg : `2999_12_31_235959_foreign_key.php`

```php
<?php

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Tag;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class ForeignKeys extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        // Post_tag
        Schema::table(Post::NOM, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('id_post')
                ->references('id_post')
                ->on(Post::NOM);

            $table->foreign('id_tag')
                ->references('id_tag')
                ->on(Tag::NOM);
        });
    }
}
```

The only con I see is not having foreign keys definition in migration.

For the pros :

- Keeping database relations
- Do not care of table creation order

Comment: IMHO, this is the best answer that you don't need to care about migrations order.

Comment: Its better approach.

Comment: What is Post::NOM? What is NOM ?

Comment: NOM is french for "name". I use constants to reference my tables' names in migrations and fixtures.

Answer (score 3):

The best and easiest thing would be to just rename the migration `yyyy_mm_dd_hhmmss_migration_name`. If your migration follows this sequence, Laravel will ensure to run the migration is sorted form of date,

Answer (score 3):

Building on the answer of Galeokerdo which suggests creating a separate migration file for the foreign keys, and putting the date in the far future, I tried it and it worked great. But then I started thinking of the rollback. It turned out that Laravel takes the reverse order when rolling back migrations. That is, the latest file is rolled back first.

Since the rollback will not work with the foreign key constraints in place, I tried putting my foreign-key-removal code in the "down" method of the separate foreign key migration, having found out that the file will execute first before all other migration files. Like thus:

```
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
   Schema::table('tablename', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->dropForeign('tablename_foreignkey_foreign');
   });
}

"tablename_foreignkey_foreign" is the name of the foreign key constraint. By default, it is 
"nameofthetable_foreignkeycolumn_foreign"
```

I just wanted to share this in case anybody is struggling with it the way I did.

Answer (score -2):

You only need to change migrations order. if bands or stage tables are below users table, MySQL don't find the references. =)