# Using a newly created column in Laravel migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table named `listings` which currently contains a column named `closed`, with a data type of `integer`. The column contains only two values, either `1` or `NULL`.

Now, I need to modify this column's data type to `timestamp`, but according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#columns) this is not possible for `timestamp` data type. I also want to set the value of this column to current date where previous value was `1` and `NULL` if the previous contained `NULL`.

Here is my strategy for this:

- Create a new column named `closed_temp` to have a default value of current date
- Set `closed_temp` to `NULL` wherever `closed` is `NULL`
- Drop `closed` column
- Rename `closed_temp` column to `closed`

Here is my code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->timestamp('closed_temp')->default(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->nullable();
        $listings = Listing::all();
        foreach ($listings as $listing) {
            if(!isset($listing->closed)) {
                $listing->closed_temp = NULL;
                $listing->save();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But, this gives me some errors:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'closed_temp'
>   in 'field list' (SQL: update `listings` set `updated_at` = 2017-06-21
>   04:50:5     8, `closed_temp` =  where `listing_id` = 3)
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'closed_temp'
>   in 'field list'
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'closed_temp'
>   in 'field list'

Is there any way to use the newly created column within a migration? If not, what other alternative is there? I also tried running a `raw_sql` query, but got the same error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by creating two separate migration files, for this the [migration order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524101/laravel-change-migration-order) was important, as the migration file which created a new column `closed_temp` had to be run before the migration file containing logic for updating the `closed_temp` column and then renaming it to `closed`.

The two migration files are copied below:

```
class AlterListingsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->timestamp('closed_temp')->default(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->nullable();
        });        

    }
}

class AlterListingsClosedFieldTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $listings = Listing::all();
            foreach ($listings as $key => $listing) {
                if(!isset($listing->closed)) {
                    $listing->closed_temp = NULL;
                    $listing->save();
                }
            }
            $table->dropColumn('closed');
            $table->renameColumn('closed_temp', 'closed');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this failed is because your database manipulation code was within your schema callback. In order to access the newly created column, the schema callback needs to finish. Calling `$table->timestamp()` doesn't create the column immediately... only once the schema callback is finished will the schema changes take effect.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->timestamp('closed_temp')->default(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->nullable();
        // You were querying closed_temp here, but it doesn't exist yet.
    });

    // Now closed_temp exists, and you can query it.
    $listings = Listing::all();
    foreach ($listings as $listing) {
        if(!isset($listing->closed)) {
            $listing->closed_temp = NULL;
            $listing->save();
        }
    }
}
```