# How can I change the order in which migrations execute in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

I have some migrations that from a tables point of view, they are not in order as one table depends on another. Thus, when I rollback, because of foreign key constraints, I get errors so I have to drop some tables manually in a certain order and then run `php artisan migrate:rollback'.

Which is the best way to change the order of migrations when I run an `artisan` command? Should I change them manually by renaming?

Comment: Either change the timestamp manually, as they're executed by the order of filename (which is ordered by the timestamp infront) OR - create a migration file that contains foreign key constraints. That way you use a migration for each table and then special migration to establish foreign key constraints.

Comment: Already answered: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524101/laravel-change-migration-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524101/laravel-change-migration-order)

Answer (score 1):

1. Drop all tables or roll back your migrations.
2. All migrations at the first part have a date so you could change the order of migrations when you change them
3. Execute all migrations.

or you can change the time of your migrations and after that use `migrate:fresh`.