# Is it possible to change the order in which tables migrate in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration, laravel-artisan

I am trying to migrate my newly created migrations. The problem is that the batch of migrations waiting to migrate is in the order in which I created the migrations using

```
php artisan make:migration
```

And thus, my `product_list` migration is trying to set a foreign key on a table that it has not yet migrated.

```
$table->foreign('product_category')->references('id')->on('product_categories');
$table->foreign('product_type')->references('id')->on('product_types')->onDelete('cascade');
```

When I run `php artisan migrate` I get these errors:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\iezonsolutions>php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2019_01_15_001617_product_list

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `iezonsolutions`.`#sql-1844_16e` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `product_list` add constraint `product_list_product_category_foreign` foreign key (`product_category`) references `product_categories` (`id`))

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\iezonsolutions\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `iezonsolutions`.`#sql-1844_16e` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\iezonsolutions\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\iezonsolutions\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Is it possible to migrate my `product_category` and `product_types` tables before my `product_list` table? Then I will be able to set the foreign keys without errors.

My migration status looks like this:

```
+------+------------------------------------------------+-------+
| Ran? | Migration                                      | Batch |
+------+------------------------------------------------+-------+
| Yes  | 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table           | 1     |
| Yes  | 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table | 1     |
| Yes  | 2019_01_14_203800_server_mode                  | 2     |
| No   | 2019_01_15_001617_product_list                 |       |
| No   | 2019_01_15_002318_product_types                |       |
| No   | 2019_01_15_002336_product_categories           |       |
| No   | 2019_01_15_002357_product_skus                 |       |
+------+------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

I want it to migrate in the order

```
| No   | 2019_01_15_002336_product_categories           |       |
| No   | 2019_01_15_002318_product_types                |       |
| No   | 2019_01_15_001617_product_list                 |       |
| No   | 2019_01_15_002357_product_skus                 |       |
+------+------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is order the date and time on filename which eventually followed by laravel to migrate database sequentially.

Comment: So it is a matter of change around the last 6 digits in the file name? I do not need to run any cache clear commands, just update the last 6 digits in chronological order of which I want to migrate first to last and re-run `php artisan migrate` ? Thanks for this

Comment: Yes, along with date if possible.

Comment: Brilliant, this now migrates correctly. However, It hasn't actually solved the foreign key error. `PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table iezonsolutions.#sql-1844_178 (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")`

Comment: `Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->increments('id'); ... });` Is how my product_categories looks

Comment: Seems to me you forgot to add the key in the schema. first add the key then add the constraint. eg. $table->integer('product_category'); then add constraint line

Comment: eg. $table->integer('product_category'); then
$table->foreign('product_category')->references('id')->on('product_categories');

Answer (score 2):

Change the names of the migration files to be a lower date time than the one you wish to run it before

[Laravel change migration order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524101/laravel-change-migration-order)

so change the name of the file to be for example

```
2019_01_15_00000_product_categories
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and example!

Answer (score 0):

Change the timestamps manually such that the file you want to be migrated first should have an earlier timestamp/date name as the file name than the files you want to be migrated later.

[Changing Migration Order](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/changing-migration-order)