# Add migration file in the migration list after certain migration

Tags: laravel, migration

I want to add a migration file after a certain migration file. When I run `php artisan make:migration create_drivers_table --create=drivers` it added in the migration list as final migration. Instead, I want it to add after a certain migration

Comment: I believe you can just rename the file as it starts with a DateTime logic, but be careful if this migration was already ran in production as it can have an unexpected behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524101/laravel-change-migration-order

Answer (score 0):

Change timestamp in the migation filename, and then call command in terminal `composer dump-auto`, - this fix links in the project.