# Error with data model in Laravel (SQLSTATE[42S01])

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

Good morning, I'm trying to do the data models for a workshop workers app.
The problem comes with the guides and images data models.
Each guide has his own image, and every image belongs to a guide.
When I try to run the migrations and Laravel throws the SQLSTATE and I don't find the error, so I would appreciate your help.

The guides migration:

```php
Schema::create('guides', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('topic')->nullable();
            $table->string('author')->nullable();
            $table->year('year')->nullable();
            $table->text('goal')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->smallInteger('assistants_quantity')->nullable();
            $table->smallInteger('duration_hours')->nullable();
            $table->string('methodology')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('image_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('image_id')->references('id')->on('images');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

The guides model:

```php
class Guide extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'guides';
    public $timestamps = true;

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'topic', 'author', 'year', 'goal', 'description', 'assistants_quantity', 'duration_hours', 'methodology'];
    protected $visible = ['title','topic', 'author', 'year', 'goal', 'description', 'assistants_quantity', 'duration_hours', 'methodology'];

    public function materials()
    {
        return $this -> belongsToMany(Material::class);

    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this -> belongsTo(Image::class);
    }

    static function search($keyword)
    {
        $result = Guide::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')->get();
        return $result;
    }


}
```

The Images migration:

```php
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

The Images model:

```php
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['image'];

    public function images()
    {
        return $this -> belongsTo(Guide::class);
    }
}
```

Update: php artisan:status image
[image: Screenshot of php artisan:status]

Comment: Can you share the error message laravel is sending. Just stating SQLSTATE  error does not help here. You will need to edit the question and write full error message.

Comment: try with php artisan migrate:reset

Comment: could you add php artisan migrate:status result ti your post ?

Comment: @DeepeshThapa yes, of course. The error that laravel's throw is ("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'guides' already exists")

Comment: @RajkumarR I tried it before, and it didn't worked

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI yes, and it only runs the laravel's default migrations.

Comment: @ErikGarciaRosa regarding the error you get , first you need to rollback the latest migration , than please add a screen capture of php artisan migrate:status to be able to help you

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI It's done

Comment: Order matter, since your 'guides' migration depends on 'images' primary key :
'images' migration must be executed before 'guides'.

You must change your migration files order
see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524101/laravel-change-migration-order

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI That worked partially! so a lot of thanks, but after changing the migrations files order, the only one that doesn't runs is Guides, with the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order matter, since your `'guides'` migration depends on `'images'` primary key : `'images'` migration must be executed before `'guides'`.

You must change your migration files order.
see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524101/laravel-change-migration-order)

Answer (score 0):

Things you can try:

- Make sure the images migration file comes before the guides migration file since the image_id is a foreign key on the guides table
- Run `php artisan migrate:reset`

Answer (score 0):

Move your image migration file upper to your guides migration file since in your guide migration file you are referencing the images_id in your foreign key. To move it. just update the date of the images migration file.

> Since your guide migration was created on `2019_12_10`, your images
>   table should be `2019_12_09 or lower`. Just rename it.